# When $\langle a+b,c+d \rangle = \langle a,b,c,d \rangle$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $a,b,c,d \in R$ be four (probably different) elements of a commutative $k$-algebra $R$, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.

Obviously,
$\langle a+b,c+d \rangle \subseteq \langle a,b,c,d \rangle$.

> When $\langle a+b,c+d \rangle = \langle a,b,c,d \rangle$?

An example in a ring $R$ with involution $\beta$ (= an automorphism of $R$ of order two):
If the following conditions are satisfied, then $\langle a+b,c+d \rangle = \langle a,b,c,d \rangle$:

**(1)** $a,c$ are symmetric.
**(2)** $b,d$ are skew-symmetric.
**(3)** $I:=\langle a+b,c+d \rangle$ is invariant under $\beta$.

Indeed, $\beta(I) \subseteq I$ (= $I$ is invariant under $\beta$)
implies that $a-b=\beta(a+b) \in I$ and then $(a-b)+(a+b)=2a \in I$, so $a \in I $ and also $b=(a+b)-a \in I$. Similarly, $c,d \in I$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since $a\in\langle a+b,c+d\rangle$ if and only if $b\in\langle a+b,c+d\rangle$ (as you noted) and $c\in\langle a+b,c+d\rangle$ if and only if $d\in\langle a+b,c+d\rangle$, the desired inclusion holds if and only if both $a\in\langle a+b,c+d\rangle$ and $c\in\langle a+b,c+d\rangle$. In other words, the desired inclusion holds if and only if there exist ring elements $r,s,t,u$ such that $a=r(a+b)+s(c+d)$ and $c=t(a+b)+u(c+d)$. I suspect there is no simpler characterization.

Comment: @GregMartin, thank you for your comment.